# string a line to new line and do not add newline at the end?

Tags: php

I have a string

```
$str = 'aaaaabbbbbcccccdddddeeeeefffffggggghhhhhjjjjj';

$pos = 0;
$tmp = 0;
while($pos<strlen($str)) {
  $tmp  .= substr($str,$pos,5)."\n";
  $pos += 5; 
}
```

I dont want to add a `"\n"` at the end of produced `$str`

```
aaaaa
bbbbb
ccccc
ddddd
eeeee
fffff
ggggg
hhhhh
jjjjj //No new line here
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
echo join("\n", str_split($string, 5));
```

http://www.php.net/str-split
http://www.php.net/join

Answer (score 1):

```
while($pos<strlen($str)) {
  if ($pos > 0) $tmp .= "\n";
  $tmp .= substr($str,$pos,5);
  $pos += 5; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to substr the newline after the while loop